# Submeter Arquivo com Form Data

Tags: php, ajax, upload

Estou tentando enviar arquivos sem utilizar o `submit` do formulário. Verifiquei que através do `formData` é possível, porém estou com um problema.
Aparentemente, o arquivo é encaminhado, visto que com a variável "`path_parts`" consigo pegar os dados do arquivo, porém não consigo direcioná-lo para uma página com o `moveupload`.

**Formulário php:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Ajax upload form</title>
<script>

var form = document.getElementById('the-form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
var formData = new FormData(form);

formData.append('arquivo', arquivo);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
xhr.send(formData);

return false; // To avoid actual submission of the form
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- The HTML -->
<form id="the-form" action="/portal/teste/upload.php"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="arquivo" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Página que recebe o arquivo:

```
<?php

$arquivo = $_GET['arquivo'];

$path_parts = pathinfo($arquivo);
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
$novoNome = 'arqteste';
$destino = 'imagens / ' . $novoNome;

echo $path_parts['basename'];
echo '<br>';
echo $path_parts['extension'];

if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
echo 'Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>' . $destino . '</strong><br />';
echo ' < img src = "' . $destino . '" />';
}else{
echo 'Erro ao salvar o arquivo.<br />';
}
?>
```

Tentei usar `_POST` ou `_FILES` no lugar do `get`, e de nenhuma forma consigo o resultado esperado.

Comment: tire este `@` do início do move_uploaded_file.

Comment: Faça tambem uma validação antes.

if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name'])){ echo 'ok'} else {echo 'vazio'};